# sublime text console activation key configuration

Tags: ubuntu, macros, sublimetext3

I read SublimeText 3 console is activated by "control" + "`" (backtick).
This character is not available in my spanish keyboard.
How I can configure this activation to be "control" + "@", by example ?
Thanks.

I did "copy" the backtick from another place, but can not "paste" it, as I am holding "ctrl"

Comment: well, I have found that "control" + "º" (1 key left to "1") does open console. Still want to configure my key.